# make command not working in Windows WSL Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, makefile, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to build a project in Ubuntu in a WSL instance. The command I'm using is from a chirpstack-simulator project: docker-compose run --rm chirpstack-simulator make clean build.
For some reason make refuses to work correctly, or at all.

I keep getting an error: "make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop."

**Here is the Makefile code:**

```
VERSION := $(shell git describe --always |sed -e "s/^v//")

build:
    @echo "Compiling source"
    @mkdir -p build
    go build $(GO_EXTRA_BUILD_ARGS) -ldflags "-s -w -X main.version=$(VERSION)" -o build/chirpstack-simulator cmd/chirpstack-simulator/main.go

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up workspace"
    @rm -rf build
    @rm -rf dist
    @rm -rf docs/public
```

**The docker-compose.yml code:**

```
services:
  chirpstack-simulator:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-devel
    command: make
    volumes:
      - ./:/chirpstack-simulator
```

**And the Docker-devel file:**

```
FROM golang:1.13-alpine

ENV PROJECT_PATH=/chirpstack-simulator
ENV PATH=$PATH:$PROJECT_PATH/build
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
ENV GO_EXTRA_BUILD_ARGS="-a -installsuffix TDM-GCC-64"

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates tzdata make git bash

RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_PATH
COPY . $PROJECT_PATH
WORKDIR $PROJECT_PATH
```

As you can see, both build and clean are defined. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

**Edit:**
This is the full project I am trying to build
https://github.com/brocaar/chirpstack-simulator

**And further details:**
I have tried doing
`sudo apt-get remove make`
`sudo apt-get install make`
then
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essentials`
It is still giving the error.

Version of Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS if it helps narrow things down

Comment: Is your makefile called `Makefile` (or `makefile`) (not something like `Makefile.mak` or whatever)?  When you run make is your working directory the one containing the makefile?  Maybe add an `ls` and/or `pwd` as a command to run, to see the contents of the directory and what directory you're in.

Comment: @MadScientist Hi, the makefile is named 'Makefile'. And how would I add those commands? I am quite new to Linux/Ubuntu and Docker as a whole. I tried adding them to the 'command': section of the docker-compose.yml like "command: ls pwd make" and they were ignored. I also tried adding them to the original command to run the build "ls | pwd | docker-compose run --rm chirpstack-simulator make clean build"

Comment: I don't know much about how that yaml format works; you'd have to ask a docker person.  Probably you need to adjust the question tags to include docker.  But, you definitely can't use something like `ls pwd make`.  You need to at least put semicolons between them: `ls; pwd; make` (not pipe symbols).  Or possibly that won't work and you should just replace `make` with `ls`, just to see what output you get, then put back `make` when you figure it out.

Comment: `docker-compose run` doesn't take arguments. Are you doing `make clean build` on a new line? Also, not sure I understand why you really need Compose here

Comment: I am just following the commands in the README, honestly. My first experience of Go/Docker was only two days ago, and this isn't my usual type of work in general, so apologies but I don't have enough knowledge of what could necessarily replace any given command here.

Answer (score 1):

I would at the very least replace the `make` command by `ls -larth`, just to make sure the [`docker-compose run ls -alrth`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) does display a `Makefile` in its execution context.

If it does not, then any `make` command would fail with the error message you mention.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Unfortunately when I try this I get an error stating "ERROR: No such service: ls". This is making me think it is a general problem with WSL, or I suppose more likely, there might have been something basic I may have inadvertently not downloaded

Comment: @JMurphySmith Strange. Is it similar to https://serverfault.com/a/1007812/783?

Comment: It doesn't seem so. I never installed docker with snap. The command I used was ```sudo apt-get install docker-compose``` from first setup and continued from there to meet the problem mentioned in the question